# Test score higher than train score

Tags: machine-learning, classification, training, naive-bayes-classifier, test

I implemented a Gaussian Naive Bayes classifier and I got a **test score (*99,99%*) higher than the train score (*96,87%*)**
Is this normal or does it mean that my model is underfitting ?
Thank you.

Comment: It could be any number of things, try a different split.

Comment: You should add more information so that we can help you better (rows quantity, type of data, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Higher performance on test data set relative to train data set can happen for many reasons. Mostly likely it is due to chance.